# Cyclic.sh is not detecting the start scrypt in package.json

Tags: express, deployment, hosting, cyclic

I came here after some hours of reading and getting into the cyclic cool deployment process. https://www.cyclic.sh/

I was trying to host my express js app for free and linked my github repo to my cyclic.sh dashboard. (I added typescript to my express app btw) The build process of my app was successful ✅ , but when I check the logs on runtime it throws me this error: ERROR: Failed to run 'node index.js'

Successful build:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enGzG.png)

The complete error log in runtime:

```
2023-01-09 01:21:26.063: grep: /var/task/package.json: No such file or directory
2023-01-09 01:21:26.527: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
Require stack:
- /var/task/index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:33:34)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/var/task/index.js' ]
}
Thrown at:
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
2023-01-09 01:21:26.527:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at /var/task/index.js:33:34
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)

Node.js v18.12.1
2023-01-09 01:21:26.562: 
ERROR: Failed to run 'node index.js'.

Exited with code: 1
```

I noticed that the problem is that cyclic is not running node in the correct directory. The correct command executed should be: `node dist/index.js`. Because of that, I added the scripts configuration in my `package.json` as it is specified in https://docs.cyclic.sh/overview/launch, but for some reason cyclic is not reading  that change in my scripts. (It works well locally)

I am not sure if I am missing something. I am very close, but I am stock at this point. I attatched some screenshots about the successful build, the failure and my package.json configuration.

My package.json file configuration:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z4c3.png)

Any help would be very appreaciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I solved this issue the same week I posted this question. I ended up doing 2 changes: 1. changed the `"main"` attribute in `package.json` from `"dist/index.ts"` to just `"index.ts"`. 2. changed the `"start"` script from `"node dist/index.js"` to `"node ./dist/index.js"`. Happy coding everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here. I use `src/index.js` and that's what in my `package.json`:

```json
"main": "src/index.js",
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  },
```

*Environments* > *Build paths* > **Output Path**: *leave it empty*, not `dist/` nor `src/`, just empty. Output Path is used to build your app from, the folder where all you libs like `node_mobules` are kept.

After that re-deploy if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue but i reslove it with simple

"start": "node dist/src/main.js",

change the package.json script and remove the

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way:

```
"start": "node index.js"
```

And not:

```
"start": "node dist/index.js"
```

I hope it works for you. happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue for app in nest with typescript and resolved by following steps

1. update package.json start script as `"start": "node dist/src/main",` and push the code
2. while deploying on `cyclic`, Click Advance > Build paths > Output Path: leave it empty, not dist/ nor src/, just empty. Output Path is used to build your app from, the folder where all your libs like node_mobules are kept.
   Also add Environment variables.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem (Let's note that I use `typescript` for my nodejs back-end project too) and the real problem was that the `package.json` file and `node_modules` folder were not in the `/dist` folder after the build command was completed. They will be outside the `dist` folder.

Scripts command in my `package.json` file before:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node dist/server.js",
"build": "rm -rf build && npm i && tsc"
}
```

I solved the problem by specifying the output folder for all emitted files in my `tsconfig.json` file, instead of `./dist`, I updated to:

```
"outDir": "./"
```

Then I updated the `start` script command in my `package.json` to:

```
"start": "node server.js"
```

And all is working well now.